# How to easily recognize whether stream is video or image [ffmpeg library]

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, codec

Having an AVStream object how should I reliably distinguish whether this is video or image stream?

I've tried to use duration. If it's 0 - we are having image (system constraints allows for such assumption). But it turns out that duration have special meaning for images - the number of images stored in file.

Is there any tricks to detect image stream more reliably?

Answer (score 0):

At first guess, I would suggest examining the `AVStream->codec->pix_fmt` enumeration (see `enum PixelFormat` [link](http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/ffmpeg-r_2libavutil_2avutil_8h.html#60883d4958a60b91661e97027a85072a) for more information).  You should be able to trim down the values that are for images and videos.  Most videos (MPEG-2/4, MOV) typically store their frames in `PIX_FMT_YUV420P` format.

I'll find you the answer tomorrow when I'm back on my development system.